# SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory

Tags: nginx

I have Ubantu 16.04

In side `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled#` this directory `default` file that contains following code:

```
# HTTPS server
server {
    listen 443 ssl; # we enable SPDY here
    server_name www.bitradiology.com; # this domain must match Common Name (CN) in the SSL certificate

    root html; # irrelevant
    index index.html; # irrelevant

    ssl_certificate /root/bitradiology.chained.crt; # full path to SSL certificate and CA certificate concatenated together
    ssl_certificate_key /root/bitradiology.key; # full path to SSL key

    # performance enhancement for SSL
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;

    # safety enhancement to SSL: make sure we actually use a safe cipher
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    .............some other code........
```

When I run the command `sudo nginx -t` it is giving following errors:

```
nginx: [emerg] BIO_new_file("/root/bitradiology.chained.crt") failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen('/root/bitradiology.chained.crt','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

**How to fix this problem?**

Comment: As a general rule: you don't put service configuration files in `/root/` so move the certificates to (a suitable subdirectory in) `/etc/` (optionally: use the correct file-system permissions to secure them from the other system users if needed. )  but the error seems to indicate that you point to a file that does not exist *".... /root/bitradiology.chained.crt") failed (SSL: **No such file or directory** :fopen('/root/bitradiology.chained.crt','r')"*